# HTML5 Beginner. I want a Speech-Box to run Java program

Tags: java, jquery, html, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I am a beginner at HTML stuff, I was looking at http://slides.html5rocks.com/#speech-input and was wondering how I could press enter on text input or speak and afterwards run a Java application HelloWorld with the input String from the text box.

I would like a simple rundown of what I need to do. If there is any advice on Text-To-Speech Output, that would be icing on the cake :)

Comment: The thumbdowns are because you have asked for general information, advice or walkthroughs, which are discouraged. Pointed questions about any step where you're stuck won't be thumbed down.

Comment: @abhranil we need to be gentle on the nubies, otherwise we chase them away!

Comment: @tnt I didn't thumb down. I helped.

Comment: +1 for counteracting the negative vote given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry this question got thumbsed-down (it wasn't me) but maybe I can help you understand how you'll need to approach the problem (and if you're up for it!):

1) The new HTML5 speech input sends its string result as a form
2) You'd need to read this input, pass it along to middle-ware client-scripter (like jQuery - learn this), then use jQuery to instantiate your Java application in the client window

Again, sorry the community felt like this question wasn't worth answering...but it is a big one!

Comment: Thanks for that, I know where to go from here at least, Appreciate it. I can't thumb you up since I have -2 reputation points starting today on stack overflow >_<